# I could not use jQueryUI draggable inside the kendo ui splitter

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I try to drag an element inside the kendoSplitter using jqueryUI draggable, but It can't. Somebody suggests set the z-index to higer, but even I could not solve this.
[Here jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zGZ3d/)

Please anyone suggests the way to solve it with the jsfiddle example.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery draggable event `dragstart` bubbles up the DOM tree and your horizontal element takes over the dragstart event.

I've taken your example and simply unbound the event from #horizontal

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    var win_width = $(document).width();
    var win_height = $(document).height();
    var top_pane_height = 50;
    var bottom_pane_height = 50;
    var middle_pane_height = win_height - (top_pane_height + bottom_pane_height);
    var kendoElement = $("#horizontal").css('height', middle_pane_height).kendoSplitter(
    {
        orientation:'horizontal',
        panes:
        [
            { size: "18%", collapsed: false, collapsible: true, resizable: false},
            { collapsible: false, resizable: false },
            { size: "18%", collapsed: false, collapsible: true, resizable: false}
        ]
    });
    $("#panelBar").kendoPanelBar();
    var draggable = $('#center-pane').find(".draggable").draggable({stack: "#center-pane"});
    kendoElement.unbind('dragstart');
});​
```